# i'm filtering divs without java and idk where to put the div on css

Tags: html, css, filter

as you can see there's a div with an id named *sidebar*. idk what to put on css for it to work.
css:

```
button[data-filter="walks"]:focus ~ div div:not([class*="walks"]),
button[data-filter="swims"]:focus ~ div div:not([class*="swims"]),
button[data-filter="flies"]:focus ~ div div:not([class*="flies"]) {
  display:none;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="filteredList">
    <div id="sidebar">
       <h3>Filters</h3>
       <button class="filter-option" data-filter="*" tabindex="-1">All</button>
       <button class="filter-option" data-filter="walks" tabindex="-1">Walks</button> 
       <button class="filter-option" data-filter="swims" tabindex="-1">Swims</button> 
       <button class="filter-option" data-filter="flies" tabindex="-1">Flies</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="animals">
       <h3>Animals</h3>
          <div class="dog walks">Dog</div>
          <div class="eagle flies">Eagle</div>
          <div class="cow walks">Cow</div>
          <div class="shark swims">Shark</div>
          <div class="canary flies">Canary</div>
          <div class="human walks">Human</div>
          <div class="salamander swims walks">Salamander</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i've tried using this:

```
#sidebar button[data-filter="walks"]:focus ~ div div:not([class*="walks"]),
#sidebar button[data-filter="swims"]:focus ~ div div:not([class*="swims"]),
#sidebar button[data-filter="flies"]:focus ~ div div:not([class*="flies"]) {
  display:none;
```

and i expected it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that CSS is always cascading.

You can't go up in structure, and CSS therefore expects the animals div to be a sibling of the buttons.

You'd need to restructure your HTML so that the filters are not nested inside the sidebar div for the snippet to work.

```
<div class="filteredList">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <h3>Filters</h3>
    <button class="filter-option" data-filter="*" tabindex="-1">All</button>
    <button class="filter-option" data-filter="walks" tabindex="-1">Walks</button> 
    <button class="filter-option" data-filter="swims" tabindex="-1">Swims</button> 
    <button class="filter-option" data-filter="flies" tabindex="-1">Flies</button>
    
    <div id="animals">
      <h3>Animals</h3>
      <div class="dog walks">Dog</div>
      <div class="eagle flies">Eagle</div>
      <div class="cow walks">Cow</div>
      <div class="shark swims">Shark</div>
      <div class="canary flies">Canary</div>
      <div class="human walks">Human</div>
      <div class="salamander swims walks">Salamander</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this change, your CSS code should work as expected and hide the div elements with the walks, swims, and flies class when the corresponding button element is focused.

Besides that, I'd recommend you to use checkboxes and ::checked for accessibility reasons.

Comment: You can do it now with the `:has` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the new [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector:

```css
#sidebar:has(button[data-filter="walks"]:focus) ~ #animals div:not([class*="walks"]),
#sidebar:has(button[data-filter="swims"]:focus) ~ #animals div:not([class*="swims"]),
#sidebar:has(button[data-filter="flies"]:focus) ~ #animals div:not([class*="flies"]) {
    display:none;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qy3wuv4b